# onKeyDown method on Android emulator is not working for physical keyboard DPAD

Tags: android

I have a custom view which has below method. My customer view loads a Sudoku board. I want to implement a cursor on the board which will allow the movement of selected square box when the user select a physical keyboard DPad. Below is the method that I have for cursor implementation.

My issue is when I press any of the DPADs from physical keyboard, nothing happens on the Sudoku board. It seems that it is not able to detect DPAD from physical keyboard.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event="
            + event);
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
            select(selX, selY - 1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            select(selX, selY + 1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            select(selX - 1, selY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            select(selX + 1, selY);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return true;
}


private void select(int x, int y)
{
    invalidate(selRect);
    selX = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8);
    selY = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8);
    getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
    invalidate(selRect);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue . Below are the resolution steps :

a) Add setFocusable(true) and setFocusableInTouchMode(true) to the constructor of the custom View

b) Enable keyboard for emulator in the avd config file.